# Discord.js V13 Player is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm building a discord.js v13.6.0 music bot and everything is working except this code

```
const { QueryType } = require('discord-player');
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['p'],
    utilisation: '{prefix}play [song name/URL]',
    voiceChannel: true,

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Write the name of the music you want to search. ❌`);

        const res = await client.player.search(args.join(' '), {
            requestedBy: message.member,
            searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
        });

        if (!res || !res.tracks.length) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, No results found! ❌`);

        const queue = await client.player.createQueue(message.guild, {
            metadata: message.channel
        });

        try {
            if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(message.member.voice.channel);
        } catch {
            await client.player.deleteQueue(message.guild.id);
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, I can't join audio channel. ❌`);
        }

        await message.channel.send(`Your ${res.playlist ? 'Your Playlist' : 'Your Track'} Loading... `);

        res.playlist ? queue.addTracks(res.tracks) : queue.addTrack(res.tracks[0]);

        if (!queue.playing) await queue.play();
    },
};
```

When I use this command, the following error occurs:

```
Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: player is not defined
```

I'm new to programming, sorry for any silly mistakes, if you need any info don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility of such errors appears either by throwing inside of a async function without a catch block or rejecting a promise which didn't had a .catch()

You might be doing:

1. you put your code inside an **async** function in order to use **await** calls.
2. The **awaited** function fails.

The solutions are:

1. Either use **.catch()**

```js
    await returnsPromise().catch(e => { console.log(e) })
```

or

2.Use try/ catch block

```js
try {
  await returnsPromise()
} catch (error) {
  console.log('That did not go well.')
}
```